# Recovering control of a domain name

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration

When I applied for a hosting package for the initial version of my web site, the hosting company (the national Telecoms company in the country where I lived) registered the domain name using their own details rather than mine.

The web site quickly outgrew the capacity of the original hosting package, and I now operate several VPS servers around the world, with the original hosting package just providing the DNS nameserver and very basic in-country services.

The Telecoms company has lost interest in hosting, and no longer answers emails, so I can no longer update nameserver records. I no longer live in that country, so I cannot visit their offices in person.

Is there any way of recovering control of my domain name?

Comment: "Is there any way of recovering control of my domain name?" Maybe. But not knowing even the TLD does not allow to really give useful answers. Find who is the registrar (if that concept exists in your TLD) and contact it. But if you are not listed as owner of the domain (check whois) you will have little hope to recover it... except if you enter long and hard negotiations with the registrar/registry and if you have proofs you paid for it, etc. etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek you have enough reputation to cast close votes now. After leaving a comment like this, please vote to close questions that need more information to be able to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

If the domain name is displayed on your invoice, you can take it to a lawyer for better ways to handle this or you will have to wait for it to become available to purchase.

Sadly there is no won't be able to recover it because it belongs to the Telecom company according to the registrar information.